# Which word does this modify?

Tags: grammar

**Every Monday and Tuesday afternoon.**

Does this mean "every Monday afternoon and Tuesday afternoon?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this means on both Monday afternoons and Tuesday afternoons. If the writer/speaker wanted to differentiate/be more specific, they would likely say something like "On Mondays and on Tuesday afternoons" - note the repetition of "on".